# Windows 10 Hyper-V Default Switch IP Assignment

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I am new to hyper-v and have used VirtualBox in the past. I am running Windows 10 version 1709. I created a new RHEL 7.5 VM and connected it to the default switch.

When I try to use my network adapter from the VM it does not connect.

Does the 'Default Switch' assign IP addresses to machines that connect to it?

Comment: Create another virtual switch and check the option 'Allow management OS....'. See this [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines).

Comment: Thank you @Biswapriyo. I tried this and while it worked it dramatically reduced the speed of my adapter to the point that it was practically unusable. Creating your own switch also seems unnecessary with the addition of the default switch and I would like to understand how to use it.

Comment: My question is above. Does the hyper V default switch provide DHCP services? I know that in general the virtual switches do not, but this seems to be a very special switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyper-v "Default Switch" does indeed assign IP addresses to guests that are connected to it.

The issue I was having seems to be related to the configuration of my workstation. When this question was first posted the switch was not assigning an IP. It nows does; it is a corporate workstation and I suspect it was behind on patches and had some restrictions set.

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V create a NAT based virtual switch called Default Switch and will connect virtual machines to that switch by default. However, you can still use the old way and set networking the way you do for traditional virtual machines.

More info [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/11/13/whats-new-in-hyper-v-for-windows-10-fall-creators-update/)

Comment: How does it change the guest's IP? Where does it get the IP that it sets?

Comment: Thank you Joe, the link is great. It states 'Yes, the default switch does automatically assign an IP to the virtual machine (DNS and DHCP)' which is the first place that I have seen such a statement made. Have you tried this in practice? When I use the default switch, my VM does not get an IP assigned.

Comment: I cannot give you a definite answer for all OS but it is doing it for Kali, Win 7 and Clear Linux, it even allows you to share your host's internet access without any other manipulations, but the latter does not apply to Kali.

Comment: Thank you Joe, I am trying to use RHEL, have you had any experience with that?

Comment: Not really, did you try to ping the host, it might work but won't allow internet connectivity in some cases (like kali), then you'll have to use the external switch. Maybe this will help https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sect-windows-rhel-guests